# Review Audit fail -- close as primarily opinion based even though others have done the same

Tags: discussion, review, new-users, disputed-review-audits

[Is it a known good practice to use a big try-catch per method in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784549/is-it-a-known-good-practice-to-use-a-big-try-catch-per-method-in-java)

**Two other people** (count says 3, but that includes me) voted to close it as primarily opinion based.  Why does this question not fall under this category?

Comment: Did they vote to close it before or after you reviewed it?

Comment: The Reopen audits selection criteria are supposed to filter questions that are controversial by not considering posts have downvotes or close votes.  I find it odd that the close vote queue wouldn't consider that.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I assume you meant **not** controversial.  And see my previous comment, if the close votes were after the review, the system wouldn't consider it controversial at the time it was an audit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 It was actually a [First Posts audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2962303).

Comment: @Servy no I meant filter out controversial post (by not including them as audits)

Comment: @animuson sorry, assumed it was a close vote audit.  But the idea is still the same- if it is controversial should be included?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Once again, if the votes to close were after the review then it may not have had any close votes or downvotes at the time it was selected to be an audit.

Comment: @Servy There were three vote to close on the post before the audit was created, and also one that was retracted.

Comment: @Servy before I reviewed it

Comment: @MartijnPieters The answers weren't in [the audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/2962303), the question was.

Comment: @Servy: Oops, it was the 'first posts' audit and a distraction that threw me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry about that; while I think this could make for an interesting question with some tweaking (perhaps on [Programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) it wasn't a very good example for an audit.

This is simply a case where the system did a bad job of picking a "known good" question - demonstrating once again that popularity isn't everything.

Comment: In fact most popular questions are now off-topic.